# In Ember.js, why is an error thrown if I set a route's path as {path: '/'}?

Tags: ember.js

I have the router.js file of my project set up as follows:

```
Router.map(function() {
  this.route('login');
  this.route('projects', {path: '/'});
});
```

Whenever I visit the `/login` page, no content is displayed. Also, the following error appears in the console:

```
Error: There is no route named index
```

However, whenever I remove `{path: '/'}` from route, the login page works without issue.

Why is this happening? I've noticed that in other Ember projects like Ghost are [able to achieve this just fine](https://github.com/TryGhost/Ghost/blob/master/core/client/app/router.js) without any conflicts with a non-existent index route.

Note: I am using an ember-simple-auth mixin to redirect the visitor from `/` to `/login`.

Comment: Try defining your index route this.route('index', { path: '/' });

Comment: While that would work, I would rather use the 'projects' route.

Comment: add an index route in the projects route.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ran into the exact same problem when I tried to add the following route to my application:
    `this.route('user', { path: '/' });`

I determined the problem was that in one of my templates I had a link like:
    `{{#link-to "index"}}Home{{/link-to}}`

Since the root (index) path now belongs to the user route, there is no index rout. I needed to update my link to:
    `{{#link-to "user"}}Home{{/link-to}}`

I suspect you might be referencing the index route, which no longer exists, somewhere in your templates or other code.  Changing that to "projects" should work for you.

Comment: Aaaah, yes. I'm using a link-to in the navigation bar. I'd completely forgotten about that!